# how to convert a python script and html files of flask application into an standalone .exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, exe

I have a python script `p1.py`
and two folders templates and static.

templates has all the necessary html files

I want to combine all of them and create an executable

I tried `pyinstaller p1.py --onefile`

But im getting the following error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

I also tried other answers on stack overflow for similar questions and nothing works

I use Mac so please give me solutions that work on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pyinstaller p1.py --onefile --add-data "templates":"templates" --add-data "static":"static"
```

This answer is for Mac.

Ref:https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/

Answer (score 1):

```
pyinstaller spec_an_API.py --onefile --add-data "templates";"templates" --add-data "static";"static"
```

For windows. Thanks @Miffy I was struggling with this forever

Answer (score 0):

You can try py2exe for your python files if that is not working you can try this post that i have found.

- http://dev.prositen.com/wp/make-a-win32-exe-of-a-python-3-flask-app/

Dont know if this will help you, let me know if it does.